# jquery not working in IE inside iframe other browsers work properly

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, iframe, compatibility, meta

A weird problem with loading jquery in iframe using IE. I tried using the meta tag in compatibility mode but still not working. Chrome and Mozilla are working fine.

Comment: How are you loading jquery into the iframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try this?

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />
```

Comment: Thanks John. Unfortunately, it does not work for this specific issue :(